# R timeseries ggseasonplot - arguments imply differing number of rows: 508, 127

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't figure out how to get rid of this error... The code is pretty simple, and the data is openly available via fpp2 package.

```
library(fpp2)
tail(arrivals)
autoplot(arrivals)
ggseasonplot(arrivals, year.labels = T, year.labels.left = T)
```

Description of the data:

> Quarterly international arrivals (in thousands) to Australia from Japan, New Zealand, UK and the US. 1981Q1 - 2012Q3.

`tail(arrivals)` produces the following:

[image]

and `autoplot` works as expected
[image]

however when I get to `ggseasonplot(arrivals, year.labels = T, year.labels.left = T)`, R generates an error:

> Error in data.frame(y = as.numeric(x), year = trunc(round(time(x), 8)), : arguments imply differing number of rows: 508, 127

Comment: I am not going to install that package just to make your code reproducible on my computer. However, I want to mention that there are 4 seasons and 4 * 127 == 508. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you did already have found the answer. But here it is:

The correct command is dependent of the country you want the stats of.
This is the answer for Japan:

```
ggseasonplot(arrivals[,1])
```

The number wetween the squera brackets is de comumn you want to display (Japan = 1, NZ = 2, UK = 3 & US = 4)

The comment of @Bernhard gave ma a clue, but its not the seasons or querters. Its the amount of columns, it exptect only on culomn with 127 rows (or in this case querters) but you gave 508 values that it could not map.